# Using MySQL, is there any way to dump the count of records in each of all 200 tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

Say if there is a database that has 200 tables, is there a quick way to see how many records are in each table, if possible, sorted by the number of records descendingly?

Comment: Do you mean: Is there a quick way to see how many records are in each *table*?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get record counts for all tables in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name,
       table_rows
  FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
 WHERE table_schema = '<Your Database Name>'
 ORDER BY table_rows DESC
```

Comment: Again: This is accurate for MyISAM, but the row count for InnoDB is just an estimate.

Answer (score 2):

Does [show table status](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) work for your problem?  It has the row counts?

Comment: Warning: This is accurate for MyISAM, but the row count for InnoDB is just an estimate.

Comment: the result is very wide, can't show each row on 1 line even when console is 250 characters wide.  Is there a way to selectively show parts of this table (and sorted on count)?