# Count(*) Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I was browsing for a solution to getting counts from multiple tables and I came across the following answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2) FROM table1
```

It works great, however I can't seem to get it to work for more than just 2 tables.  My current code is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE3),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE4),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE5),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE6),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE7),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE8),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE9),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE10),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE11),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE12),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE13),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE14),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE15),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE16),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE17),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE18)
FROM TABLE19
```

However, it only counts TABLE1 and TABLE19.  I need to count all tables (TABLE1-18) as well as TABLE19 (hopefully using a structure to similar to the first example).

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: i think you are solving the wrong problem here .. why exactly you need to do this query ?

Comment: There has to be a more efficient way to accomplish this task. I'll +1 @MarkByers question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which DB this is it could slightly change...

For Oracle do something like:

```
Select (select count(*) from table1) as table1Count, 
       (select count(*) from table2) as table2Count
from dual
```

If it's SQL Server then just leave off the from dual.

EDIT:

Since you mentioned you are using MySQL in the comments:

[Get record counts for all tables in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database)

Comment: Used a solution from the link.

Answer (score 2):

Use aliases so that the columns have unique names:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1) AS count_table1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2) AS count_table2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE3) AS count_table3,
    etc..
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE19) AS count_table19
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to accept the results in rows, not columns, you can always use a UNION:

```
SELECT "table1", COUNT(*) FROM table1 UNION                         
SELECT "table2", COUNT(*) FROM table2 UNION                         
SELECT "table3", COUNT(*) FROM table3
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL this works:

```
select sum(total) from(
select count(*) as total from Table1 
union
select count(*) as total from Table2) as a;
```