# Select count from each table from a list stored on a table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table `tbls` with a field `name` containing names of tables.

I'm trying to form a statement to get the number of rows of each of this tables.

Should I use a stored procedure or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thread that talks about how you can [Get record counts for all tables in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database). Using the result, you can constraint the result set to tables specified in the tbls table.