# what is the fastest way to count a large table using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I finding trouble deciding what is the fastest way to count some specifc records from my tables filtered by a where statment
here is my code, here are the queries:

```
$type_mo3ln_malk = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tableshow` $weress AND mo3ln_type='malk'"));
$type_mo3ln_mswg = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tableshow` $weress AND mo3ln_type='mswg'"));
$type_mo3ln_mktb = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tableshow` $weress AND mo3ln_type='mktb'"));
$type_mo3ln_wkeel = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tableshow` $weress AND mo3ln_type='wkeel'"));
$type_mo3ln_no = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tableshow` $weress AND mo3ln_type='0'"));
```

the function that do the count are the one which is predefined in php

I am thinking of using count() function but I am wondering if I could use Sum function for some specific rows only as Mr.Hates suggested here
[Get record counts for all tables in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database)

Comment: Whenever the question goes like _is a faster or b_, the only real answer is to setup a test and benchmark it for yourself.  The RDBMS is highly optimized already for performing aggregate functions like `COUNT()`, so it is possible that the aggregate will be faster than calling `mysql_num_rows()`.  But that also depends on your table's indexing, size, and other factors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth Did you build a browser plugin that detects mysql_*() and auto-inserts that comment or something? :)  If so, post it to stackapps!

Comment: @Michael: I use http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se. Happy commenting! :D

Comment: @Truth Aha! I knew it must be something like that.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `whatever`='whatever';
```

Will return a single row (instead of over 9000), containing the correct count based on the rules you've set.

Answer (score 1):

This should be even faster:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE mo3ln_type WHEN 'malk'  THEN 1 END) AS cnt_mo3ln_malk,
       COUNT(CASE mo3ln_type WHEN 'mswg'  THEN 1 END) AS cnt_mo3ln_mswg,
       COUNT(CASE mo3ln_type WHEN 'mktb'  THEN 1 END) AS cnt_mo3ln_mktb,
       COUNT(CASE mo3ln_type WHEN 'wkeel' THEN 1 END) AS cnt_mo3ln_wkeel,
       COUNT(CASE mo3ln_type WHEN '0'     THEN 1 END) AS cnt_mo3ln_no
FROM   tableshow
WHERE  mo3ln_type IN ('malk', 'mswg', 'mktb', 'wkeel', '0')
```

This will get all of your counts in one single `SELECT` statement rather than five separate statements.

Provided that you have an index set up on the `mo3ln_type` column, the `WHERE` clause should narrow down your rows fairly quickly, then it's just a matter of conditionally aggregating those rows within `COUNT()`.

It would be even faster if you represented each `mo3ln_type` as an integer instead of a string as the comparisons on numbers is much faster. Perhaps you can create another table storing the different `mo3ln_types` and in the `tableshow` table, just have a foreign key reference to the INT primary key in `mo3ln_types` instead of the actual text string. (e.g. `WHERE mo3ln_type_id IN (1, 2, ...)` instead of `WHERE mo3ln_type IN 'malk', 'mswg', ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table_name> WHERE <where_clause>;
```

Or (if you make pagination, for example) use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, if you want also make query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM <table_name> WHERE <clause> LIMIT 0, 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

more info: [MySql Information Functions -> FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

And if you want to get only counts use the SUM function:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN mo3ln_type = 'malk'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS malk,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mo3ln_type = 'mswg'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mswg,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mo3ln_type = 'mktb'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mktb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mo3ln_type = 'wkeel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wkeel,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mo3ln_type = '0'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_type
FROM   tableshow
WHERE  <where_clausw>
```

more info: [MySql Control Flow Functions -> CASE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case), MySql Aggregate Functions -> SUM function *

- dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Answer (score 0):

A database always preforms work much faster than the application layer, thus returning the count from the database using the `Count(*)` command is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the database to count the rows, not PHP. Use COUNT(*) in the SQL statement.

```
function f_count_rows($table, $where='') {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS nbr FROM `".$table."` ".$where);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  return $row['nbr'];
}

$type_mo3ln_malk  = f_count_rows("tableshow", $weress." AND mo3ln_type='malk'");
$type_mo3ln_mswg  = f_count_rows("tableshow", $weress." AND mo3ln_type='mswg'");
$type_mo3ln_mktb  = f_count_rows("tableshow", $weress." AND mo3ln_type='mktb'");
$type_mo3ln_wkeel = f_count_rows("tableshow", $weress." AND mo3ln_type='wkeel'");
$type_mo3ln_no    = f_count_rows("tableshow", $weress." AND mo3ln_type='0'");
```