# mysql sum count from multiple table using wildcard

Tags: mysql

I have tables like A_0, A_1,...A_9, and I want to count all rows number or delete them:

```
select count(*) from A_*;
delete from A_*;
```

Is wildcard support or should i walk around another way?

Comment: If you are looking for all counts, from all tables, you could work with the schema like shown here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database  .

Comment: walk around other way

Answer (score 0):

select won't target several different tables , unless you Join/Union them to form a middle step result.

like this:

```
select
    count(*)
from 
    ( select * from A1 
      union all select * from A2 ....)
```

no table wild card supported in sql