# How to know if row count is exact or approximate

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to get approximate row counts in a mysql table:

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'avails';
```

[image]

My questions is, is there an additional parameter that shows if the row count is exact or approximated? If not, how is this done in a client like SequelPro where it can show an immediate number of table rows, and it will add a tilda (~) if it is not an exact count?

[image]

[image]

Comment: ***Is there an additional parameter that shows if the row count is exact or approximated?*** No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database however provides an example on how to use system tables to dynamically query counts for all tables to get an exact count.

Comment: @xQbert got it, thank you. Then how does a client like SequelPro know if it's exact or approximate? It isn't using COUNT(*) because the # rows loads instantaneously.

Comment: Based on [this OLD document/link](https://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/issues/detail?id=141)  All I can gather is if they query system tables they use a ~ if they query the table using count(*) then they don't.