# Why indexes don't work for count(*)?

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL, too late until I realized that that queries took too long to respond needed required columns to be indexes. 
 
I understand the way that indexes work, but I'm wondering if indexes could be implemented in a way that COUNT(*) or COUNT(col1) where col1 is indexed, would be as fast as executing **'WHERE COL=007'**? 
I ask this because in my application I often need to make the count query. Decreasing the response would be much needed for a faster operation flow.

Comment: What is your query? Having a `count(*)` in the select portion should not prevent an index from being used.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database

Comment: MySQL doesn't use indexes on count or sum target columns. It has to iterate on each row for providing the results.

Answer (score 1):

You say you understand how indexed work. But I think that is also a question of how aggregate functions work.

Lets say you make a

```
SELECT count(col) FROM table;
```

What does it do? Probably it presents every col from that table to *count* and *count* does a

```
counter++;
```

somewhere. That is a rather fast operation.

The speed of your *count query* depends on how fast each row can be presented to the *count* function. The index on *col* does not affect the speed because each row of *table* has to be scanned anyway. Indexes are only a means to find certain rows faster than a complete table scan.

On the other hand, a fast query like

```
SELECT count(col) FROM table WHERE col="rare value";
```

is fast because the

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col="rare value";
```

is fast as well.

I hope this makes sense to you. Otherwise, why don't you provide us with some more detail and we try and pimp a real-life query?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` can be evaluated in *O(1)*, from table metadata. The table knows how many rows it has. It doesn't require a scan. Or an index.

Comment: Maybe with your MySQL Version. I am using 5.6.35 which is not too old. And I get `SELECT count(*) FROM countTest;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   500000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,12 sec)` which doesn't seem to be O(1)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-group-by-related-conditions.html says:  "If the table handler has a quick row-count available, then the query

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1; `

gets the count without going through all the rows. This is true for MyISAM tables, but not for InnoDB tables."