# How to quickly retrieve the table with the most rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

The database is on a remote Linux server, I am using Windows.

I want to retrieve the table with the most rows in MySQL, but I am on a Windows client.

I have about **200 tables**. I have to **click their table name**  one by one to figure out the row count.

The databases has many tables, I can get their rows by executing

`select count(*) from table`

This will retrieve the rowcount one by one.

## My Question

Is there a quick method to get the table with the most rows in MySQL workbench on Windows?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` is about a fast as I know of.  Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: MyISAM tables iny MySQL stores rows count in table meta. Other table types counts the rows, when you execute the same SQL statement.

Comment: I have about 200 table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
      ,TABLE_ROWS 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC
```

Comment: For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  MAX(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
```

=> This will return the maximum number of rows a table have.

```
SELECT  table_name, MAX(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
```

=> This will return the maximum number of rows a table have with the table name

**Quick Links**

1. [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)
2. [Get record counts for all tables in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database)

Comment: For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{{schema_name}}'
ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will tell you the table name with most number of rows. Replace schema_name with your database before executing query.

Comment: this won't work, you're using an aggregate function, but no GROUP BY

Comment: For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.)