# Procedure with loop to save number of registration in each table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to do an loop with cursor which will take number of registration in each table. And after display "name : result".

I have this structur :

```sql
DELIMITER  $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  num_reg  $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  num_reg ()
BEGIN
   DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT count (*) FROM database;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
    OPEN cur1;
    first_loop: LOOP
    
    -- here I save result of cursor in variable and I display it.

    END LOOP first_loop;
    CLOSE cur1;


END $$
```

I don't know how I can take informations. And I don't know name of table in advance.

Exemple:
If I have my database shop with 2 tables buyer and seller in each table I have 2 rows
When I execute Procedure output is :
buyer : 2
seller : 2

Comment: Not sure why you want a loop. A `count(*)` query will return only one row containing a count (a number)

Comment: How to use Cursors ([Tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/)) should be all you need

Comment: number of registration in each table? You could clarify by adding tables (2 should be enough) sample data and expected outcome..

Comment: I edited the subject

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get record counts for all tables in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database)

Comment: No that don't answere because don't use procedure and here I don't know in advance name of tables

Comment: Look again answer with 12 score my jake drew does..