# SQL Search database for column name & return counts of NULL and NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been using this simple query as a way to find data when I'm working on new queries for my coworkers. Is it possible to upgrade it to return a 4th and 5th column that reports how many rows are in the Table and how many NULL values are in the column? That would save me so much time during my exploration.

```
SELECT      
TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'SchemaName'
,TABLE_NAME AS  'TableName'
,COLUMN_NAME AS 'ColumnName'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%cost%'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
ORDER BY    TableName, ColumnName;
```

Comment: You'll need to build a dynamic query on top of this to sum the counts using a case expression.

Comment: Might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database

Comment: @RaghavGarg that question is for MySql, it won't help with SQL Server

Comment: Oh, right, my bad I didn't notice the sql-server tag.

Comment: You can get the RowCount with a `CROSS APPLY` but the NULL count will probably require some dynamic sql which will really expand this query.

Comment: You shouldn't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` it's for compatibility only. Instead use `sys.tables`. The row-counts are available from `sys.partitions`, you may be able to get `null` information for some tables using statistics, but you're probably going to need dynamic SQL. If you do, don't forget to use `QUOTENAME` to quote column names

Comment: I wasn't aware of sys. After learning that, getting row count was pretty straightforward. Thanks